# Jedis "couldn't get pool resource" on a Storm topology

Tags: java, redis, apache-storm, jedis, bigdata

I have my topology running, every bolt works, except the redis bolt. I am trying just to write info to a redis database, and I have found an example online. The topology works, however, when the DB bolts executes it shows this error:

```
3594 [Thread-18-print] INFO  b.s.d.executor - Processing received message FOR 22 TUPLE: source: meal:20, stream: default, id: {}, [2009 +1.2815365e-01  :-)  :-)]
source: meal:20, stream: default, id: {}, [2009 +1.2815365e-01  :-)  :-)]
13595 [Thread-18-print] INFO  b.s.d.executor - BOLT ack TASK: 22 TIME:  TUPLE: source: meal:20, stream: default, id: {}, [2009  +1.2815365e-01  :-)  :-)]
13595 [Thread-18-print] INFO  b.s.d.executor - Execute done TUPLE source: meal:20, stream: default, id: {}, [2009   +1.2815365e-01  :-)  :-)] TASK: 22 DELTA: 
13595 [Thread-38-bd] ERROR o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxnFactory - Thread Thread[Thread-38-bd,5,main] died
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NodeExistsException: KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /errors/test-1-1454011533/bd-last-error
    at backtype.storm.util$wrap_in_runtime.invoke(util.clj:49) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.zookeeper$create_node.invoke(zookeeper.clj:92) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.cluster$mk_distributed_cluster_state$reify__4580.set_data(cluster.clj:106) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.cluster$mk_storm_cluster_state$reify__5120.report_error(cluster.clj:465) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$throttled_report_error_fn$fn__5469.invoke(executor.clj:193) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor_data$fn__5523$fn__5524.invoke(executor.clj:256) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__545.invoke(util.clj:489) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) ~[clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_91]
Caused by: org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NodeExistsException: KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /errors/test-1-1454011533/bd-last-error
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:119) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.create(ZooKeeper.java:783) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$11.call(CreateBuilderImpl.java:676) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$11.call(CreateBuilderImpl.java:660) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:107) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(CreateBuilderImpl.java:656) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.protectedPathInForeground(CreateBuilderImpl.java:441) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:431) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$3.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:239) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$3.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:193) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor38.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93) ~[clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28) ~[clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at backtype.storm.zookeeper$create_node.invoke(zookeeper.clj:91) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    ... 7 more
```

Or this other(s'ha refusat la connexió = connection refused):

```
13375 [Thread-48-bd2] ERROR b.s.util - Async loop died!
java.lang.RuntimeException: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:135) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:106) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:80) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5694$fn__5707$fn__5758.invoke(executor.clj:819) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__545.invoke(util.clj:479) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_91]
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:50) ~[jedis-2.7.0.jar:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:86) ~[jedis-2.7.0.jar:?]
    at Storm.practice.Storm.Prova.ProvaTopology$RedisBolt.publish(ProvaTopology.java:175) ~[classes/:?]
    at Storm.practice.Storm.Prova.ProvaTopology$RedisBolt.execute(ProvaTopology.java:157) ~[classes/:?]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5694$tuple_action_fn__5696.invoke(executor.clj:690) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__5615.invoke(executor.clj:436) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__5189.onEvent(disruptor.clj:58) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:132) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    ... 6 more
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: S’ha refusat la connexió
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:154) ~[jedis-2.7.0.jar:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:83) ~[jedis-2.7.0.jar:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1643) ~[jedis-2.7.0.jar:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:85) ~[jedis-2.7.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:861) ~[commons-pool2-2.3.jar:2.3]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435) ~[commons-pool2-2.3.jar:2.3]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363) ~[commons-pool2-2.3.jar:2.3]
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:48) ~[jedis-2.7.0.jar:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:86) ~[jedis-2.7.0.jar:?]
    at Storm.practice.Storm.Prova.ProvaTopology$RedisBolt.publish(ProvaTopology.java:175) ~[classes/:?]
    at Storm.practice.Storm.Prova.ProvaTopology$RedisBolt.execute(ProvaTopology.java:157) ~[classes/:?]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5694$tuple_action_fn__5696.invoke(executor.clj:690) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__5615.invoke(executor.clj:436) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__5189.onEvent(disruptor.clj:58) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:132) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: S’ha refusat la connexió
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:148) ~[jedis-2.7.0.jar:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:83) ~[jedis-2.7.0.jar:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1643) ~[jedis-2.7.0.jar:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:85) ~[jedis-2.7.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:861) ~[commons-pool2-2.3.jar:2.3]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435) ~[commons-pool2-2.3.jar:2.3]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363) ~[commons-pool2-2.3.jar:2.3]
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:48) ~[jedis-2.7.0.jar:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:86) ~[jedis-2.7.0.jar:?]
    at Storm.practice.Storm.Prova.ProvaTopology$RedisBolt.publish(ProvaTopology.java:175) ~[classes/:?]
    at Storm.practice.Storm.Prova.ProvaTopology$RedisBolt.execute(ProvaTopology.java:157) ~[classes/:?]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5694$tuple_action_fn__5696.invoke(executor.clj:690) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__5615.invoke(executor.clj:436) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__5189.onEvent(disruptor.clj:58) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:132) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    ... 6 more
```

And I have no idea why it is unable to have the resources. And I am not sure if this bolt would just write the ACK'ed tuples. I hope that someone knows how to fix it(there are a lot of unused imports, but it is because I am getting mad trying to get it to write to a Redis database, I have no idea about how to get it done, this is just a test, I am working on a big-data project, and I will need to understand this database connection):

```
package Storm.practice.Storm.Prova;
import backtype.storm.Config;
import backtype.storm.LocalCluster;
import backtype.storm.StormSubmitter;
import backtype.storm.task.OutputCollector;
import backtype.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import backtype.storm.testing.TestWordSpout;
import backtype.storm.topology.BasicOutputCollector;
import backtype.storm.topology.IRichBolt;
import backtype.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
import backtype.storm.topology.base.BaseBasicBolt;
import backtype.storm.topology.base.BaseRichBolt;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields;
import backtype.storm.tuple.ITuple;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Tuple;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Values;
import backtype.storm.utils.Utils;
import backtype.storm.spout.SpoutOutputCollector;
import backtype.storm.topology.base.BaseRichSpout;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.apache.storm.redis.bolt.AbstractRedisBolt;
import org.apache.storm.redis.bolt.RedisStoreBolt;
import org.apache.storm.redis.common.config.JedisClusterConfig;
import org.apache.storm.redis.common.config.JedisPoolConfig;
import org.apache.storm.redis.common.mapper.RedisDataTypeDescription;
import org.apache.storm.redis.common.mapper.RedisLookupMapper;
import org.apache.storm.redis.common.mapper.RedisStoreMapper;
import org.apache.storm.redis.trident.state.RedisState;
import org.apache.storm.redis.trident.state.RedisStateQuerier;
import org.apache.storm.redis.trident.state.RedisStateUpdater;
import org.apache.storm.shade.com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisCommands;

import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool;
//import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPubSub;
import storm.trident.Stream;
import storm.trident.TridentState;
import storm.trident.TridentTopology;

/**
 * This is a basic example of a Storm topology.
 */
public class ProvaTopology implements Serializable {

  public static class ProvaBolt extends BaseRichBolt {
    OutputCollector _collector;

    public void prepare(Map conf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
      _collector = collector;
    }

    public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
      _collector.emit(tuple, new Values(tuple.getString(0) + "  :-)"));
      _collector.ack(tuple);
    }

    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
      declarer.declare(new Fields("Morts"));
    }


  }
  public class ProvaSpout extends BaseRichSpout {
      SpoutOutputCollector _collector;
      //Random _rand;
      private String fileName;
      //private SpoutOutputCollector _collector;
      private BufferedReader reader;
      private AtomicLong linesRead;

      public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context, SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
        _collector = collector;
        try {
            fileName= (String)"prova.tsv";
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            // read and ignore the header if one exists
          } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
          }
       // _rand = new Random();
      }

      public void nextTuple() {
        Utils.sleep(100);


      try {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line != null) {
              //long id = linesRead.incrementAndGet();
              System.out.println("Finished reading line, " + line);
              _collector.emit(new Values((String)line));// id));
            } else {
              System.out.println("Finished reading file, " + linesRead.get() + " lines read");
              Thread.sleep(10000);
            }
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }

      public void ack(Object id) {
      }

      public void fail(Object id) {
      }

      public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("Morts"));
      }

    }

  public class RedisBolt implements IRichBolt {

        protected String channel = "Somriures";
        //    protected String configChannel;
        protected OutputCollector collector;
        //    protected Tuple currentTuple;
        //    protected Logger log;
        protected JedisPool pool;
        //    protected ConfigListenerThread configListenerThread;

        public RedisBolt(){}
        public RedisBolt(String channel) {

        //  log = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
        //  setupNonSerializableAttributes();
        }

        public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context,
                OutputCollector collector) {
        this.collector = collector;
        pool = new JedisPool("localhost");
        }



        public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
        String current = tuple.getString(0);
        if(current != null) {
            //      for(Object obj: result) {
            publish(current);
            collector.emit(tuple, new Values(current));
            //      }
            collector.ack(tuple);
        }
        }

        public void cleanup() {
        if(pool != null) {
            pool.destroy();
        }
        }

        public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields(channel));
        }

        public void publish(String msg) {
        Jedis jedis = pool.getResource();
        jedis.publish(channel, msg);
        pool.returnResource(jedis);
        }

        protected void setupNonSerializableAttributes() {

        }

        public Map getComponentConfiguration() {
        return null;
        }
    }



  public class PrinterBolt extends BaseBasicBolt {

      public void execute(Tuple tuple, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
          System.out.println(tuple);
      }

      public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer ofd) {
      }

  }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
   ProvaTopology Pt = new ProvaTopology();
   JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig.Builder()
            .setHost("127.0.0.1").setPort(666).build();



    builder.setSpout("Morts", Pt.new ProvaSpout(), 10);//emisorTestWordSpout
    builder.setBolt("happy", new ProvaBolt(), 3).shuffleGrouping("Morts");// de on llig?
    builder.setBolt("meal", new ProvaBolt(), 2).shuffleGrouping("happy");// de on llig?
    builder.setBolt("bd", Pt.new RedisBolt(), 2).shuffleGrouping("meal");// de on llig?
    builder.setBolt("print", Pt.new PrinterBolt(), 2).shuffleGrouping("meal");
    builder.setBolt("bd2", Pt.new RedisBolt(), 2).shuffleGrouping("happy");
   // builder.setBolt("StoreM", (storeMapperS));
    Config conf = new Config();
    conf.setDebug(true);

    if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
      conf.setNumWorkers(5);

      StormSubmitter.submitTopology(args[0], conf, builder.createTopology());
                                   //WithProgressBar
    }
    else {

      LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
      cluster.submitTopology("test", conf, builder.createTopology());
      Utils.sleep(10000);
      cluster.killTopology("test");
      cluster.shutdown();
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came with the answer yesterday, what I needed is to change the localhost to 127.0.0.1, then I launched the Redis database on a terminal, on a second terminal the monitor, and my publish method was working.